# Swap one 'td' element with another while dragging between tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

[image]I am making a UI in which I have two tables which are in different `div`'s.
I want to swap one `td` element in one table with another one in the other table while performing a dragging function.

I have tried some libraries like kento and jquery sortable but I was not successful.

Can you please tell me how to do it with pure JavaScript or some library.

Here is my HTML code for one table:

```html
<div id="jumbo">
  <div class="fool">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="item" style="background-color:blue">english</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="item" style="background-color:blue">english</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="background-color:yellow" class="item">hindi</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="background-color:yellow" class="item">hindi</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="background-color:red" class="item">maths</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="background-color:red" class="item">maths</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="background-color:grey" class="item">physics</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="background-color:grey" class="item">physics</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="cool" draggable="true">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
          <th>lunch</th>
          <th>5</th>
          <th>6</th>
          <th>7</th>
          <th>8</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sortable list">
          <td draggable="true" style="background-color:green">monday</td>
          <td draggable="true" style="background-color:red">eng</td>
          <td draggable="true" style="background-color:blue">hindi</td>
          <td draggable="true" style="background-color:yellow">maths</td>
          <td draggable="true" style="background-color:red">eng</td>
          <td draggable="true" style="background-color:blue">hindi</td>
          <td draggable="true" style="background-color:yellow">maths</td>
          <td draggable="true" style="background-color:red">eng</td>
          <td draggable="true" style="background-color:blue">hindi</td>
          <td draggable="true" style="background-color:yellow">maths</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have only one table in your code. Try adding the below code in your current HTML as a starter and proceed. Using this you can move `<td>` parallel only. Just use this idea of dragging and develop. Better have 2 separate table to achieve your requirement.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jqueryUi.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {

$("td").draggable({ containment: 'parent'}).resizable();

});
```

Comment: actually there are two table one table is formed dynamically in the 'div' named 'cool'.

Comment: i took some data and edited that 'div' with the table data  i am getting after dynamic generation please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...but color is not copied...need to do some parsing for that..try and let me know:)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jqueryUi.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

$(".fool div").draggable({ containment: '#cool'});

$("#cool div").draggable({ containment: '.fool'});
$("#cool").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
               console.log(event.target.outerHTML);

               $("#pushed").append('<tr class="copied"><td>'+event.toElement.firstChild.parentElement.outerHTML+'</td></tr>');
               ui.draggable.remove();
               $("#pushed div").removeAttr( 'style' );
               //$("#cool div").not(".copied").remove();
            }
        });


});
</script>

<div id="jumbo">
  <div class="fool">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="item" style="background-color:blue">english</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="item" style="background-color:blue">english</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="background-color:yellow" class="item">hindi</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="background-color:yellow" class="item">hindi</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="background-color:red" class="item">maths</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="background-color:red" class="item">maths</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="background-color:grey" class="item">physics</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="background-color:grey" class="item">physics</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="cool" style="background-color: aquamarine;width: 106px;height: 136px;" >
  <table id="pushed">

  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the div is draggable and while dragging it got removed but its not performing swapping it is just sitting over the element

Comment: i have added the pic of my ui after your code was applied